# Handle component remounting with react-navigation (same implementation, different result)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobile-application, native-base

I've got a problem which I cannot seem to solve.

I have an app built with react-native and expo and react-navigation.
What I am trying to achieve:
A user can sign up for an event. All events the user wants to participate are listed on one screen. Pressing on one marks this event as "active" - The user can (on another screen) now see details and a bulletin board for this event.

```
Hierarchy:
- Loginstack (not relevant, just for completion)
- Homestack
-- Home
-- Eventstack (Active Event)
--- Details
--- Bulletin Board
-- Create Event
-- Sign up for Event
-- List Events User goes to
```

From the Sign up Screen I navigate to the Eventstack while first add the Event to local storage. The Details Screen now checks for the active event and loads the data. When the user navigates away from this screen and back to it, the Details screen should only reload the data if the active event has changed! First, the Stack Navigation:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="EventDetails" headerMode="none" screenOptions={({ route, navigation}) => ({
            animationEnabled: false,
        })}>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="EventDetails"
                component={EventDetailsScreen}
                initialParams={{ active: EventFooter.details, }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Bulletin"
                component={BulletinScreen}
                initialParams={{ active: EventFooter.bulletin, }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

My Code:

```
const EventDetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [eventToLoad, setEventToLoad] = useState(null);
    const [event, setEvent] = useState(null);
    const userData = useContext(UserContext);

    const _loadEvent = async (eId?: number) => {
        setLoading(true);
        let eventId: number = eId || await getActiveEvent();

        if (eventId == null) {
            if (userData.user.event.id === undefined) {
                return;
            }

            eventId = userData.user.event.id;
        }

        const eventToSet = await findEventById(eventId);
        setEvent(eventToSet);
        setLoading(false);
    };
    const _checkEvent = async () => {
        const actEvent = await getActiveEvent();
        setEventToLoad(actEvent);
    }

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            _checkEvent();
        }, [])
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        _loadEvent();
    }, [eventToLoad]);

    return ( ... );
};
```

For this code the following is happening. The first time the user navigates to the Details Screen the Event Details are loaded from the server via useEffect. When I now navigate away and back to this screen useFocusEffect would set the Active Event Id. If it is the same as before, useEffect will not be fired... Working. Logs are saying the same. The first time the active event is set, for all next navigations to the details sreen the already set data is used. Now for the Bulletin Board (same Hierarchy level) I implemented it the same way.

```
const BulletinScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [eventToLoad, setEventToLoad] = useState(null);
    const [threads, setThreads] = useState<Array<Thread>>(null);
    const userData = useContext(UserContext);
    const _getThreads = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        let eventId: number = await getActiveEvent();
        if (eventId == null) {
            if (userData.user.event.id === undefined) {
                return;
            }

            eventId = userData.user.event.id;
        }

        const threadsToSet = await getThreads(eventId, userData.user);
        setThreads(threadsToSet);
        setLoading(false);
    };
    const _getEvent = async () => {
        const actEvent = await getActiveEvent();
        setEventToLoad(actEvent);
    }

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            _getEvent();
        }, [])
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        _getThreads();
    }, [eventToLoad]);

    return ( ... );
};
```

This time, every time I navigate to the bulletin screen the initial states (null) are used and therefore trigger a reload, which is not what I want.
I use a stack navigation and native-base for a footer tab navigation, which is used to navigate between the Details and Bulletin Screen. Do I have a blind thinking spot? It is the same implementation, right? Why does it behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up: Stack Navigation just works that way... Tab Navigation does not. So it works with a Tab Navigation.